# How to get uicontrols by their ID in iphone dev environment

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I'm just starting to learn the iphone API, and I've done plenty of windows programming, and I'm sure there's a way, given the object passed to an event handler, to identify its object id or tag or something.

I created a series of UIButtons in the interface builder, and each has an object ID.
But I just can't see where in the iphone API you can get that ID from the UIButton object.

I see everybody going by titleforstate, but that doesn't work for me because they all have the same title. Or do I put an image in the button and use the title as the ID?

The interface builder has an "interface builder identity" which I'm guessing I don't have access to from the iphone API, do I?

There's also a setting called "Tag" in the "view" section of the button attributes, but it's a number. That will do,  but I don't see any API call to get that either.

I'm just trying to figure out how to identify a UI control by some means other than it's title.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's inherited from NSObject, you just need to call for variable.tag

Comment: marvelous. I looked in every other object that UIButton inherits from except for NSObject. Thanks.

Comment: stu, if you approve this as the answer it will help others who have the same question find it.

Comment: And to go along with that is UIView's handy "viewWithTag:" method.

Answer (score 2):

The provided answer works fine for me, but where is it documented?  I look at NSObject Protocol Reference and there is no mention of a tag attribute or method.

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    int tagNum = [sender tag];
```

[edit] It turns out that tag is in [NSView](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCBGFHJ), not NSObject.  Anything that inherits from NSView has a tag attribute.